# Remove the ProjLib logo from the title page (beaulivre package)

Tags: titles, logos

I like the title (cover?) page of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/beaulivre/beaulivre-doc-en.pdf) of the [beaulivre](https://ctan.org/pkg/beaulivre) package and want to do emulate the same for a document. I copied the code from the [`.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/beaulivre/beaulivre-doc-en.tex) file of the package documentation.

```
\TitlePage [ color = { main = forestgreen!75!black, back = forestgreen!10!yellow!30 } ]
{
    , title     = Title
    , subtitle  = Subtitle
    , author    = Name
    , date      = {\today}
}
```

[image: titlepageimage]

How do I remove the ProjLib logo? I couldn't find anything in the documentation of either the ProjLib or the beaulivre package. It would be nice if there is some option to insert any other logo/image in that place.

Comment: It's nice that you like it :)

Comment: @Jinwen Thank you for creating such nice packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\TitlePage [ color = { main = forestgreen!75!black, back = forestgreen!10!yellow!30 } ]
{
    , title     = Title
    , subtitle  = Subtitle
    , author    = Name
    , date      = {\today}
    , logo      = {} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Wow, As simple as that! How did you figure it out?

Comment: @Apoorv Potnis  See `projlib-titlepage.sty`  line #60.